# Outline css is completely ignored by some gmail clients

Tags: css, gmail

I'm encountering problems when sending emails using outline css (inline is working just fine) since last week. outline CSS is completely ignored.

Please note same email without changes that worked fine a week ago is now displayed without any outline css applied to it.

I'm also encountering this problem while rendering a gmail client using email on acid.

This code works:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
         <body>
         <p style="font-size:300px> large text </p>
         </body>
</html>
```

While this code isn't:

```
<html>
  <head>
        <style>
             .test {
             font-size:300px }
        </style>

  </head>
         <body>
         <p class="test">large text </p>
         </body>
</html>
```

I expect outline css to be respected by gmail like it did a week ago. Something has changed in the way gmail is now rendering css. Strangely some gmail accounts receive an email with the outline css applied and some received it with the outline css completely ignored (same exact email!).

Comment: Hi @Barak, you should check out [campaignmonitor's CSS guide for emails](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) which includes a good list of supported / not supported CSS in email clients :)

Comment: Hi @Jake, thanks for replying. According to the list you sent, gmail is listed as supporting <style> in head (outline css). While in practice as I mentioned it's totally ignored in some google account (this seems random which gmail account are being affected). Please assist further. Thanks again

Comment: Just to clarify things - the problem is with regarding Internal style sheet (=outline css).

Comment: It's really odd because I just reviewed Gmail's documentation and nothing seems to have changed from their side. Ref - [Gmail documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css) Btw this was last updated on April 23, 2019. Can you double check if something else from your side may have caused this change the way it is rendering now?

Answer (score 0):

As odd as it might sound what solve the problem is refershing all the gmail clients that ignored the outline css. I suppose this force the app restart itself in chorme and the bug was solved (even for emails already sent).

In short:
1. Close all opened gmail tab opened in whether browser you're using (the problem occured in both chorme and firefox as far as I tested).
2. open new browser window.
3. go to gmail.com
4. hit the refersh buttom of the browser to make sure the gmail web app is reloaded.